# How to grab the image tags only from each nested element?

Tags: jquery, html, each

How can I grab the image tags only from each nested element?

For instance,

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#" class="box"><span><img src="thumb-pic-1.jpg" alt="123" /></span></a><a href="#"><img src="static-contraption.png" width="357" height="252"/></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="box"><span><img src="thumb-pic-2.jpg" alt="123" /></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

I just want these image tags,

the first list item,

```
<img src="thumb-pic-1.jpg" alt="123" />
<img src="static-contraption.png" width="357" height="252"/>
```

second list item

```
<img src="thumb-pic-2.jpg" alt="123" />
```

my working jquery,

```
$(".box").each(function(){          

            var object = $(this);
            var object_image = $('img', object).parent().html();
            alert(object_image);

        });
```

result for the first list item,

```
<img src="thumb-pic-1.jpg" alt="123" /> // which is not right as I want two of those image tags
```

result for second list item

```
<img src="thumb-pic-2.jpg" alt="123" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/t8NpD/1/

### jQuery

```
$("li").each(function(){    

   $(this).find('img').each(
        function(index, element){
        alert( $(element).attr('src') );
    })

});
```

Use `$(element).attr( attr_name )` to get attribute you need.